# MVC-Routing,Why i can not ignore defaults,The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this configuration

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "TestRoute",
               url: "home/MyTestDrillDown/{productcat}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "MyTestDrillDown" }
           );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I want to configure TestRoute as

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "TestRoute",
               url: "home/MyTestDrillDown/{productcat}"
           );
```

but i see following error.
**The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required**.

My understanding is that if i have a hard coded a url then it directly matches to a controller and an action, in my case `"home/MyTestDrillDown/{productcat}"` matching to *HomeController* and *MyTestDrillDown* action.

I am sure i am missing something very basic and important here as there exists an overload of `MapRoute` method which takes only *Name* and *Url* as parameter.

Thanks

Comment: if someone else is looking at this question, please do read the comments of the chosen answer too..as some of the extended questions are asked and answered in the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MVC pipeline needs the `controller` and `action` route values. If you define your route as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TestRoute",
    url: "home/MyTestDrillDown/{productcat}"
);
```

when a url matches this route, a single route value will be extracted by the routing system, the `productcat` parameter. There will be no `controller` and `action` route values extracted. That's why you need to define such a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TestRoute",
    url: "home/MyTestDrillDown/{productcat}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "MyTestDrillDown" }
);
```

This way, when a url matches this route, there will be `controller` and `action` route values extracted (even though they are defined as default values and not extracted from the actual url)

You need to bear in mind that the routing system is independent from MVC, and happens earlier in the ASP.Net [pipeline](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application), before the MVC specific code is run.

When you call `routes.MapRoute()` you are just calling an [extension method](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/RouteCollectionExtensions.cs) that will add a `Route` instance to the route table. Every route you add in ASP.Net needs an `IRouteHandler` which in turn returns an `IHttpHandler`. All the routing system does to find the first route that matches the current url and extract the route data values. It is then the route handler the component that will start the specific code handling the request matched by that route. (See [routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the msdn).

In the case of MVC, using the `MapRoute` extension adds an [`MvcRouteHandler`](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/MvcRouteHandler.cs), which in turn returns an [`MvcHandler`](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/MvcHandler.cs). The `MvcHandler` is the one that starts the MVC specific pipeline. For example, take a look at the `ProcessRequestInit` in the source code, and you will see how it **requires** a route value named `controller`, which is used to create the controller instance:

```
string controllerName = RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
```

where [`RouteData.GetRequiredString`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Routing/RouteData.cs#53e98bd9e4c39be5) throws an exception if there is not a route value with such a name in the parameters extracted by the route. (This is the exception you noticed in your question)

Comment: Thanks, Very well explained.you said "There will be no controller and action route values extracted",i have always thought of {controller} and {action} as some kind of placeholders, values for which are extracted from the matched url and if we want we may specify the Defaults. That said i am not sure then what is the use of the overloaded MapRoute extension method which does not take this third parameter for specifying the defaults? By defaults i understand if there is a matched url and system is not able to find a contrlr/action then switch to this cntrlr/action.kind of fallback for a matched

Comment: [..continue from last] Now by analyzing it again i think there is not point in defining a route named "TestRoute", i could have modified the action to take input param as "id" and not "productcat" and default route named "Default" would have worked fine. Having another route here i think is just an overhead. i think i have written a lot in comment please take time to read both the comments and kindly reply my queries. thanks.

Comment: When you define a route like `{controller}/{action}`, you are matching urls with 2 segments, and giving names to the values matched by those segments. If you define it like `home/MyTestDrillDown`, there will be no controller and action values unless you add default values, because there are no named segments like `{controller}` and `{action}`

Comment: Regarding the overload without default values, I am sure there will be usages of that overload, there are too many different requirements out there! Imagine none of the url segments are optional and for some reason you want ids in the query strings. In that case you could define the route as `{controller}/{action}` with no default values.