# routes.MapRoute Confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routeconfig

I know it's the general approach:

```
routes.MapRoute
    (
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

But If I try like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute
    (
          name: "Defaults",
          url: "Home/Index/1"
    );
```

It will not give any error to run the project. I have `Controller = Home` `Action = Index()` in my `HomeController` but why It is giving error while I type this `http://localhost:1702/Home/Index/1`in my browser?

> Error: The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value,
>   which is required.

Which part is mandatory in Routing? 
Another question is: Why we need `Route Name`?? If I give `name=""`, it works fine even more than one Route is exists like `name=""`

Comment: `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`?

Comment: No. If you try like me it will not give you any error. I know the routes.MapRoute become like you. By default it has three parts. name, url and defaults, I know this

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752298/mvc-routing-why-i-can-not-ignore-defaults-the-matched-route-does-not-include-a) can help? your question seems like a duplicate.

Comment: May be but what about the second question?

Comment: If you just use: `http://localhost:1702` does this go to `home/index/1`?

Comment: *Which part is mandatory in Routing? Another question is: Why we need Route Name?* The answer to that can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.maproute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you need this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: I know it's the general approach. If I dont use defaults what will be the problem??

Comment: @LutforRahman There is an [overloaded method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.maproute(v=vs.118).aspx) that states that you don't need `defaults`..  so why don't you try it?

Comment: Why this will give overload if I indicate my Controller, action and id in my browser? Will you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

url is to define the url structure for end user. You can even change it to

```
url: "{action}/{controller}/{id}"
```

So to understand which is controller and which is action you have to provide the url structure.